# Collections.max(array) is Not Working - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am using Collections.max(array); to determine what the largest number in the selected array is. However when i use it, i get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method max(Collection<? extends T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (int)

    at Array_6.main(Array_6.java:23)
```

My code is as follows:

```
    int input;
    int highestNumber = 0;
    int arrayNumber = 0;


    int[] intArray = new int[10];

    System.out.println("This application determines the highest number out of 10 inputed numbers");
    System.out.println("Welcome, please input the first number:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.print(i+1 + ": ");
        input = TextIO.getlnInt();  // Retrieves input
        intArray[i] = input;
    }

    highestNumber = Collections.max(arrayInt);

    System.out.println("Highest Number is " + highestNumber);
```

*EDIT*

I did what was recommended below, and the message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int
Bound mismatch: The generic method max(Collection<? extends T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<int[]>). The inferred type int[] is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>

at Array_6.main(Array_6.java:24)
```

appears, so I changed the int highestNumber into an array. Then this error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Bound mismatch: The generic method max(Collection<? extends T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<int[]>). The inferred type int[] is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>

at Array_6.main(Array_6.java:24)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collections` is a utility class for the collections API.  `arrayInt` is an array of `int` which is completely incompatible with anything the `Collections` class offers

<strike>You could try using...</strike>

```
highestNumber = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(intArray));
```

Which wraps the `intArray` in a `List` interface, making it compatible with the `Collections` API

As @LouisWasserman has pointed out, the above won't work, as `Collections.max` will expecte an `Object` not primitive based `Collection`.

The simplest solution might be too simply check each value as it's entered, for example....

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + 1 + ": ");
    input = TextIO.getlnInt();  // Retrieves input
    intArray[i] = input;
    highestNumber = Math.max(input, highestNumber);
}
```

Or you could also use `Arrays.sort(intArray)` to sort the `intArray` and simply pick off the last element in the array, which will be the highest...

Or you could create a second loop and iterate through each element in the `intArray` using `Math.max` to find the largest value...

Or you could create a `List<Integer>` collection and add each item from the `intArray` to it and then use `Collections.max`...

Or you could use a `Integer[]` array instead of an `int[]` array...

Or you could create a `List<Integer>` collection instead of using arrays altogether...

Comment: I inputed the code incorrectly, but the error is still the same

Comment: @Jordan.McBride See update (also, this is a good reason why having an accurate example helps alot ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer: `Arrays.asList` does not work the way you expect it to for `int[]`.  It returns a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`.  I don't believe there's a one-line solution for this in the JDK.

Comment: why not use List<Integer> to begin with instead of int[]? Then this conversion won't even be necessary.

Comment: @Leo That was the first option under the "simplest" solution *"Or you could also use `Arrays.sort(intArray)`"*

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8,

```
highestNumber = Arrays.stream(intArray).max().getAsInt();
```